# Angular ASP.NET MVC Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

In our MVC 5 project we use Angular. The following Razor works nicely:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName,
          new { required = "required", ng_model = "FirstName" })
```

However, if the MVC **Model.FirstName** is set to "Bob" when the page is rendered, the Input field is still blank.

If I set this in the Angular controller:

```
  $scope.FirstName = "@(Model.FirstName)";
```

Then "Bob" appears.

My question is: Do I have to set the **$scope.VARIABLE=MODEL.VARIABLE** for every field in the UI, or can I tell Angular to respect what came over from ASP.NET MVC.

Angular is appearing to over write the [input value="Bob"] that MVC writes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no need to separate the model into individual fields when you bind to scope. Instead you should bind the entire model:

```
 $scope.model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

This would render to the client as:

```
 $scope.model = { FirstName: 'John', LastName:'Doe', etc };
```

Then you can bind your input fields as:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName,
      new { required = "required", ng_model = "model.FirstName" })
```

Personally, I think its cleaner not to use @Html, in favor of simple HTML:

```
<input ng-model="model.FirstName" required />
```

In Angular, you don't really need an id anymore.

Comment: That is really great. Perfect. i'll mark it as the answer once SOF lets me.

Comment: And what to do when your angular code is in a separate *.js file?

Comment: <script> app.module('app').value('model', @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); </script>.  The rest of the module definition can be in its own separate file. 'model', can then be injected as needed.

Comment: I could see how this could be used effectively in ASP.NET if there is a real need to fetch the data and serve the initial page in the same request.  However, sending two requests may fit better with the angular framework.

Comment: Will your last line of code, in html, be caught by a POST request from mvc?

Comment: @CularBytes You will need to set Name attribute if you mean to bind razor

<input ng-model="model.FirstName" name="FirstName" required />