# How can i use MVC Editor Templates using AngularJS in a view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have used MVC and jquery to create different Question types in a view using MVC Editor templates in one of the project. See code example

`@Html.EditorFor(model => (model).UserIfno.Questions[0], "QuestionTextBox");`

Now i want to Use the Angular with MVC to achieve this Task.

Please share Best approach to achieve this.

Comment: Simply you can't use `@Html.EditorFor` in angularJs.

Comment: I now but how can i achieve this functionality with angular. I am just start using angular and need expert opinion.

Comment: see this ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275104/angular-asp-net-mvc-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Idea how to achieve this using Angular.

If any body else required please see this =>
[Angular Static and dynamic templates](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2013/12/28/angularjspart-6-templates/)