# Adding Angular validation to @Html.EditorFor

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add angular validation for @Html.EditorFor. Please see code below.

--> This is how I get the partial view from the controller

```
$scope.editClient = function () {
    var id = 1;
    $http.get('/Clients/GetClientByClientId?id=' +id)
    .then(function (response) {
        debugger;
        var divTemplate = response.data;
        var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('id_chosen_view'));
        element.empty();
        element.append(divTemplate);
        $compile(element)($scope);
    })
}

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editCompany">Company</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required="required", id="editCompany" } })
    <span style="color: red;" ng-show="formEditClient.Company.$touched && formEditClient.Company.$invalid">Company name is required.</span>
</div>
```

but this works

```
<label for="inputContactPerson">Contact Person</label>
<input id="inputContactPerson" type="text"
       class="form-control" ng-model="editClient.ContactPerson" name="ContactPerson" required/>
<span style="color: red;" ng-show="formEditClient.ContactPerson.$touched && formEditClient.ContactPerson.$invalid">Contact Person is required.</span>
```

I would like to use the first code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you declare your form?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275104/angular-asp-net-mvc-binding